# Best way to check if array is numeric

Tags: php

Say i have a one dimensional array of 500,000 cells and I want to know if this array is numeric, the most obvious options are either to iterate on the whole array and use the is_numeric() function or to use an array_shift. The problem with that is that both of these options are O(n) (correct me if I'm wrong) and will be more expensive as the data in the array grow.
I'm thinking of another way but I'm not sure of its O, which is to search for all the non numeric values in the array using regex and array_search. What do you think and are there any less expensive options?

Comment: Complexity is O(n) actually. And you won't be able to lower it unless you control the way this array is populated (so that you're able to check elements when they're to be added).

Comment: Do you know if the array is going to have non-numeric values?

Comment: There is no other *reliable* way.

Comment: Thanks @zerkms I think you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would implode be efficient? If you have a simple array, I would join all the elements together into a string and run it against is_numeric. At least you would only have to do the numeric check once.

```
$foo = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ....);
$bar = implode('', $foo);

var_dump(is_numeric($bar));
```

Comment: I think is_numeric allows stuff like hex and decimals and exponential notation. So the OP could have an original data point that is hex, but when imploded onto other things, appears to no longer be numeric.

Comment: @MeganSquire that makes sense. Guess it depends on the data the OP is working with.